# How to use Python Exception in the code given below

Tags: python, exception

Q: Write a Python program to do the following:

1. Write a recursive Python function that has a parameter representing a
   list of integers and returns the maximum number stored in the list.
2. Use Exception Handling to test if the list item is NOT integer and handle
   it.
   hint: The maximum is either the first value in the list or the maximum of the rest of
   the list, whichever is larger. If the list only has 1 integer, then its maximum is
   this single value, naturally.

My code:

```py
def maxim(maximum , lst , i ):
    if i == len(lst):
        print(maximum)
    elif maximum < lst [ i ] :
        maximum = lst [ i ]
        return maxim(maximum, lst , i+1 )
    else :
        return maxim(maximum , lst , i+1 )

lst = eval(input("Enter a list :-"))       
maxim(lst[ 0 ] , lst , 1)
```

I've answered point 1, how can I answer point 2?

Comment: Your function doesn't actually implement point 1, because it doesn't `return` the maximum, it just prints it.  For point 2, it's not clear how the exception should be "handled".  If a function is defined as taking a list of integers, the normal behavior would be for it to raise an exception if the input has the wrong type, and this code will mostly do that automatically without you having to "handle" anything.  If it's supposed to do something else, that behavior needs to be defined -- e.g. what should the `maxim` of a mixed list of strings and ints be?

Comment: if the list has a variable , It should show a message that please enter only integer.

Comment: What should it *return* in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Taking it piece by piece:

> Write a recursive Python function that has a parameter representing a
> list of integers and returns the maximum number stored in the list.

```
def maximum(nums: list[int]) -> int:
```

> If the list only has 1 integer, then its maximum is this single value,
> naturally.

```
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return nums[0]
```

> The maximum is either the first value in the list or the maximum of
> the rest of the list, whichever is larger.

```
    return max(nums[0], maximum(nums[1:]))
```

> Use Exception Handling to test if the list item is NOT integer and
> handle it.

The best place to do this is outside the function call:

```
try:
    print(f"Maximum: {maximum([1, 2, 3, "oops"])}")
except TypeError:
    print("please enter only integer")
```